Does $SU(2,2)$ act on $2\times 2$ skew-Hermitian matrices?
We can put a Hermitian form of type $(2,2)$ on a four dimensional complex vector space and define the group $SU(2,2)$ be the group of matrices that preserve the Hermitian form and have determinant equals $1$. More explicitly, we can let the Hermitian form be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&I_2\\I_2&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Then an element $g$ in $SU(2,2)$ is of the form
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are $2\times 2$ complex matrices satisfying
$$
A^*C=-C^*A,~ A^*D+C^*B=I_2,~ B^*D=-D^*B
$$
and also $\det g=1$. Here $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$.
We can also consider $2\times 2$ skew-Hermitian matrices, i.e. $2\times 2$ complex matrices $H$ satisfying $H=-H^*$.
Now for $
g=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}
\in SU(2,2)$ and $H$ a skew-Hermitian matrix, we can define the action of $g$ on $H$ as
$$
g\cdot H:=(AH+B)(CH+D)^{-1},
$$
which is an analogue of the Mobius transformation. It is clear that $g\cdot H$ is defined for all $H$ such that $CH+D$ is invertible.
It seems to me that whenever $g\cdot H$ is defined, it is again a skew-Hermitian matrix. For example in the case that $C=0$. The condition of $SU(2,2)$ then becomes
$$
D=(A^*)^{-1},~ AB^*=-BA^*, \det(A(A^*)^{-1})=1.
$$
Hence
$$
g\cdot H=AHA^*+BA^*
$$
so it is clear $(g\cdot H)^*=-g\cdot H$.


My question is for a general  $
g=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}
\in SU(2,2)$  and a skew-Hermitian $2\times 2$ matrix $H$ such that $g\cdot H$ is defined, could we prove that $g\cdot H$ is still skew-Hermitian?


